# Connecting sqlite in c++ using clion

Tags: c++, sqlite, clion

I want to develop a project in c++ which connects to an SQLite database. I've downloaded the header files (sqlite3.h, sqlite3.c, etc) as well as the sqlite3.dll from the [sqlite download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and have placed all files into the C:\sqlite directory.
I'm using CLion IDE for the project.
All I want to ask is what to add in the CMakeLists.cmake (cmake) file to include sqlite in my project. 
I've to submit the project this week so please suggest a solution as soon as possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Super basic way' Just add sqlite3.c to your project source files.

Comment: And delete the dll; you don't need it if you compile sqlite directly into your project.

Comment: @Shawn what about sqlite3.h file then?

Comment: It has to be present too, of course.

Comment: Better way: Add sqlite3.c to your project source files, add CMake configuration tests for the [platform configuation options](https://sqlite.org/compile.html#_platform_configuration), and a `config.h` that defines them and any optional sqlite features you want (And/or disable things you don't need), and make sure you compile sqlite3.c with `_HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H` defined so it includes `config.h`.

Comment: If you don't know how to do any of that... find a reasonably decent and up to date cmake tutorial, as that's all really basic cmake stuff.

Comment: Actually, I don't know Cmake yet. I'll try looking it up in a tutorial and will appreciate if you could explain me somewhere else as this is not the place to...

Answer (score 0):

To add **SQLITE** to your **CLion**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sqlite-database

In your **CMake** file write it to find your **SQLITE**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (Tutorial)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
add_executable(tutorial new.cpp)
find_package (SQLite3)

if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries (tutorial ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)
```

To add **SQLITE** via current path into **CMakeList**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (HelloWorld)
add_executable(helloworld example.cpp)
include_directories(/usr/include)
link_directories(/usr/lib)
target_link_libraries(tutorial sqlite3)
```

Comment: I'm on windows, and all the files are in the C:\sqlite directory and even after typing that I'm getting `.../MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3`